# Drawing D3 Rectangles

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner with D3 and JS in general.
I am trying to do a simple rectangle visualisation with a small csv file as a source.

```
price, units
80.67, 100
80.87, 99
79.34, 47
```

File, csv are in the same folder.
I am using Python's SimpleHTTPServer to serve locally in this folder.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Data</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // load csv from the same directory
        d3.csv("test.csv", function (data){

            return {
                        price: +data.price, // convert to number with +
                        units: +data.units, // convert to number with +         
            };

            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.price; })
                    .attr("height", 48)
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.units; })
                    .attr("fill", "blue");

            canvas.selectAll("text")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "white")
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.units + 24; })
                    .text( function (d) { return d.units;})


            });



    </script>
</body>
```

I am getting no errors, just a blank page.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in your callback is to return. None of the code after that is being executed. I'm referring to

```
return {
                    price: +data.price, // convert to number with +
                    units: +data.units, // convert to number with +         
        };
```

which should probably be

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.price = +d.price;
  d.units = +d.units;
});
```

The signature of the callback should also be `function(error, data)` instead of `function(data)`.

Comment: I replaced my return with your data.forEach and added function(error, data). Now I am getting an error "Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"" and the html is showing only one rectangle instead of three.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you!! After inspection of the csv I recognized that I had a space between the comma and the value: like: 80.67, 100. After deleting the space I have: 80.67,100 and it works now. But I am still puzzled why this space is causing error

Comment: Actually, I think I got it: the space matters only in the header row of the csv file. It should be price,units. If I place a space like this: price, units then only one rectangle will be displayed. It seems of no impact having many spaces between comma and values. Probably because I am anyway converting the strings to values.